# yum command not found, cannot install stress

Tags: centos, yum, suse

When I try to install the `stress` package on SUSE11 and Centos 7, `yum` tells me that it isn't found or that `stress` as a command does not exist.  Anywhere I have looked online tells me that it is as easy as `sudo yum install stress`, but that doesn't work.

I have managed to get it installed on SUSE thanks to the answer below but still cannot install it on Centos 7. When I run `sudo yum install stress` it says that `no package provider can be found for stress` and when I use `yum-config-manager` it tells me that the `command cannot be found`. How can I install stress package on Centos7?

**edit**

I have tried `sudo zypper install stress` and it hasn't worked, it says `no provider of stress found` and `nothing to do.`.  The same thing happens `stress*` is used as well.

Comment: It's `zypper`, not `yum` on SUSE. Make sure you are root.

Comment: ok I tried that and no it says no provider of stress found, nothing to do and have tried this with the wildcard as well. Do you know a way around this? the command i used was sudo zypper install stress

Comment: Welcome! Could you edit the question to point out what the actual problems are, which commands were tried, and what the results were? ("seemingly impossible" and "apparently does not work" is hard to understand)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel it has been made known he's using the wrong pkgmanager

Comment: @Virusboy You mean the hint to `zypper` in the first comment? I think his answer says he tried and it does not work?

Comment: yes @VolkerSiegel, I meant his comment, although he should edit his question to reflect he tried it.

Comment: @Virusboy and VolkerSiegel-above question edited to reflect your comments.

Comment: "it told me that wget was also not a command despite this being included in the url" what do you mean by `wget` being included in the url? That doesn't seem to make sense at all. Update your question to make it clear. And **please** leave out the Edit stuff commentary stuff, the system is fully capable of tracking your edits, and we can review what changed if we want to (it is way more important to have an understandable question for future visitors, so rewrite the question in a single coherent whole).

Comment: FWIW, I mostly agree, but I think the *edit* part is helpful, so that people who are trying to help can see what new things OP tried since last time.

Comment: @Mikel For the few that are concerned with the changes,  there is the edit history. We should IMO focus on ease of reading for future visitors coming here with similar problems. If I'm involved in a Q that gets updated I either know remember what was lacking or hit the `edited .. mins ago` link to open in another window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some repositories.

From looking at the [OpenSUSE listing for stress](http://software.opensuse.org/package/stress), I think you can get it from the [server:monitoring repository](https://build.opensuse.org/project/repositories/server:monitoring).

With SUSE 11, I *think* this command should add the repository.

```
cd /tmp
wget "http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/monitoring/SLE_11_SP3/server:monitoring.repo"
zypper addrepo "server:monitoring.repo"
```

With CentOS 7, maybe the CentOS 6 repository from the same site will work?  Try:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo "http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/monitoring/CentOS_CentOS-6/server:monitoring.repo"
```

Then try the `zypper install` or `yum install` again, e.g.

```
zypper refresh
zypper install stress
```

or

```
yum install stress
```

Comment: @gogoud I already have this page open, but how can I install them onto my command line? I don't want them installed on Windows

Comment: @paul try this: `/sbin/OCICLI http://software.opensuse.org/ymp/server:monitoring/openSUSE_13.2/stress.ymp?base=openSUSE%3A13.2&query=stress`

Comment: I entered that into the command line and it returns [1] 7133, [2] 7162 and [3] 7186 on the many attempts and nothing else. What does this mean?

Comment: @paul I can't vouch for that command, but you'd need double quotes around the URL.  Otherwise the `&` sign is making it run in the background with part of the URL missing.

Comment: @gogoud the above suse one worked fine thanks, but the centos one is not working yet. it tells me that bash: yum-config-manager: command not found. do I need to type anything else before it? what mistake am I making?

Comment: @Mikel the suse url in the main answer worked ok but the centos one in the answer returned the error bash: yum-config-manager: command not found. do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: As a result of my help here, and despite being awarded points for it, I have been blocked from answering questions on this forum. Rude and ridiculous! Hopefully @paul you got all the answers you needed in the end.

Comment: i don't understand it either. it worked for suse but i abandoned the centos for debian. thanks for your help though