# "No package stress available, nothing to do" and "bash: yum-config-manager:command not found

Tags: linux, centos, package-management, yum, configuration

I am trying to install the stress package on CentOS 7 virtual machine running on vmware player on windows 7 laptop. I have tried many packages and have updated yum but whenever I run `sudo yum install stress` it tells me that there is `no such package stress available and there is nothing to do.` When I run it from the following download links using `yum-config-manager`, it tells me that there is `no yum-config-manager command found.` The download links are

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo "http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/monitoring/CentOS_CentOS-6/server:monitoring.repo"

/sbin/OCICLI http://software.opensuse.org/ymp/server:monitoring/openSUSE_13.2/stress.ymp?base‌​=openSUSE%3A13.2&query=stress
```

How can I bypass these and download the stress package successfully? I want to use it to stress the vm but can't get past these hurdles. I am from an Ubuntu background and it was a lot easier on that. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [yum command not found, cannot install stress](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186249/yum-command-not-found-cannot-install-stress)

Comment: You asked this yesterday: please don't spam the wiki...

Comment: Actually I feel that this is a new question as the first one apparently did not meet the criteria despite numerous edits and I have in fact exhausted all of the previous suggestions on the other question, which was in fact different. So this is not spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to add an OpenSuSE repo? `zypper` and `yum` aren't compatible. If you're trying to get the `stress` application installed [it's in EPEL](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/stress.html) so you'll have to [add the EPEL repo](http://archive.linux.duke.edu/pub/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html) even if you're on CentOS.

Comment: so what would the syntax be install that on my centos7 vm from that link? Forgive me, I am from an Ubuntu background mainly so am not used to this.

Comment: I think you have confused "from an Ubuntu background" with "being unable to consult Google."

Comment: @Bratchley The links provided don't work and when I search for them using yum-config-manager it says that it has searched all of the mirrors and can't find it. What is the exact syntax for downloading stress successfully? Why is it such a nuisance compared to SUSE or Ubuntu?

Comment: @paul If you're on CentOS 7 [then this is the package to install](http://archive.linux.duke.edu/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/epel-release.html).

Comment: For future reference if you google the word "EPEL" the main page for EPEL's website should be the first result you get. EPEL is almost universally used for Enterprise admins so it's a well-known and well maintained repo.

Comment: RHEL software installation is not really a nuisance in general. This is just because the `stress` package isn't used by many RHEL admins (for whatever reason) so you have to add the EPEL repo. If you're going to manage RHEL/CentOS systems, adding EPEL to each of them is probably a good idea.

Comment: Actually, it looks like they even took `stress` out of EPEL for RHEL7 (only RHEL6 has the package). From what I can tell it's [in the RHEL7 version of Repoforge](http://repoforge.org/use/) but I can't confirm since I try not to use anything other than EPEL+Base channels.

Comment: Ok well it says that it package epel-release-7-5.noarch already installed and latest version but when I use the stress command, it says it does not exist. Does this first message mean that stress has been installed successfully? If so, what is the correct syntax since I am getting errors using stress --cpu1 for example.

Comment: Please see my last comment, I was looking at the RHEL6 version of EPEL before (which does have `stress`) but the RHEL7 version of EPEL doesn't have that package. You'll have to try to install the repoforge `yum` repo and see if you can get it installed that way or try to use another program to do what you're wanting.

Comment: when i try installing using http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm preceded by yum-config-manager or rpm -ivh it is just freezing. Is this the right syntax? I don't suppose you know of any commands which perform a similar function to stress within centos7?

Comment: That's the correct syntax. If it's hanging, it's probably not able to download the RPM or something. You may try to do a `wget` on it then just do the `rpm -ivh` on a local file. What does "stress" do exactly? I can't find anything specific online other than it's some kind of workload generator.

Comment: it tells me that wget is not found and when I try to download it, it fails all of the mirrors. stress is exactly that, just a workload generator that can target certain areas, I have managed to get it working in Ubuntu and SUSE ok, but not Centos. I could just use other workload generators-what I want to create workload for is vmstat, iostat and sar at the moment. Do you know any workload generators I could use instead on centos7?

Comment: What kind of workload does it generate? If it's just basic I/O there's `iozone` and `bonnie++`.

Comment: If `wget` isn't installed, that is one package available from the base channel so you should be able to just `yum install -y wget`

Comment: In the end, I just moved back to centos6, thanks for your help